# How to replace string with certain format in python

Tags: python, string

i am trying to do string manipulation based on format. str.replace(old,new) alllows changing by specific string pattern. is it possible to find and replace by format? for example,
i want to find all datetime like value in a long string and replace it with another format
assuming % is wildcard for number and datetime is `%%/%%/%%T%%:%%`

```
str.replace(%%/%%/%%T%%:%%, 'dummy value')
```

EDIT: 
sorry i should have been more clearer. re.sub seems like I can use that, but how do it substitute it with a date converted value. in this case, e.g.
    YY/MM/DDTHH:MM to (YY/MM/DD HH:MM)+8 hours

Comment: You might find this easier with a regular expression, using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), rather than trying to invent your own pattern syntax. You can even use a function to process the match and provide the replacement, allowing trivial reformatting via `datetime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably using a combination of regular expression syntax, applying [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) and using the fact that the `repl` parameter can be a function that takes a `match` and returns a string to replace it, and [`datetime`'s syntax for `strptime` and `strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import re
>>> def replacer(match):
    return datetime.strptime(
        match.group(),  # matched text
        '%y/%m/%dT%H:%M',  # source format in datetime syntax
    ).strftime('%d %B %Y at %H.%M')  # destination format in datetime syntax

>>> re.sub(
    r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}',  # source format in regex syntax
    replacer,  # function to process match
    'The date and time was 12/12/12T12:12 exactly.',  # string to process
)
'The date and time was 12 December 2012 at 12.12 exactly.'
```

The only downside of this is that you need to define the source format in both `datetime` and `re` syntax, which isn't very DRY; if they don't match, you'll get nowhere.